# How to match specific string pattern using REGEXP (or similar) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using the below UPDATE statement to update a flag that confirms if a Code is correctly formatted, note the code can be anywhere in 'RefCode'.
This works in Excel, but I understand MySQL REGEX is a little different to standard REGEX:

```
UPDATE tblRequests
SET flagIsRefCodeOK= (RefCode REGEXP '^[A-Z0-9]{8}-(?:[A-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Z0-9]{12}$')
WHERE DataSetID=11;
```

In a nut shell, it should be true/[1] if the field contains `ddda999d-99de-999e-999e-9b9bf9999999`:

```
8 alphanumeric characters
A SINGLE DASH
4 alphanumeric characters
A SINGLE DASH
4 alphanumeric characters
A SINGLE DASH
4 alphanumeric characters
A SINGLE DASH
12 alphanumeric characters
```

Would appreciate any assistance with this.

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you cannot use `(?: non-capture groups )`

Do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET flag = `1`
WHERE mycolumn REGEXP "^[[:alnum:]]{8}-([[:alnum:]]{4}-){3}[[:alnum:]]{12}$"
```

Note that the POSIX class `[:alnum:]` matches ASCII letters a-z, A-Z and digits 0-9

Comment: FYI Updated to use POSIX class `alnum` which matches ASCII digits and letters

Comment: That's great, can we tweak so that it will pick up that pattern among other text. ie: //The Code is ddda999d-99de-999e-999e-9b9bf9999999!//

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was night time. Yes! All we need to do is remove the start and end anchors: (the caret `^` and dollar `$`at the ends) `...REGEXP "[[:alnum:]]{8}-([[:alnum:]]{4}-){3}[[:alnum:]]{12}"` Let me know if you need more tweaks. :)